# Python 2.7.3 Why is my textbox relief not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create an email client. Since I am testing the program on Mac OSX, I have realized that I can't see the text box without relief. So, I attempted to set it to `GROOVE`.

```
def mainFun(self):
    """Holds body of thing"""
    self.entryFrame = Frame(self)
    self.entryFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)


    self.Body = Text(self.entryFrame, width = 75, height = 50, relief = GROOVE)
    self.Body.grid()
```

**But, the text box is still flat. Why is this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...because the borderwidth is 0 by default.

Comment: ... and for `GROOVE`, it needs to be at least 2.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  I see a difference between a borderwidth of 1 and no relief specified v. a borderwidth of 1 and relief = GROOVE.  And I see another difference once the borderwidth reaches 3.  Mac OSX 10.6.8, python 3.2.3.

Comment: yes, you'll see a difference. It's just that it's impossible to draw an actual groove with a single-pixel line. You'll still get a visible border, it just won't look much like. Groove.